# Document outline controls disabled in Visual Studio 2019 for .Net Core

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

Now that .net core support WinForms projects, I've ported an old project to .Net 5. I can edit code, desing GUI and compile, and everything seems to work fine except for Document Outline window (in Visual Studio 2019). All four buttons, move up, down, out and into, are disabled, so I cannot choose what to see on top at desing time.

I have created a new project from the scratch and those controls are still disabled.

Demo image:
[image: Visual studio issue screenshot]

Any idea why? I can guess it's something microsoft is working on, but I cannot find any reference to this issue.

That's how it looks like for .Net 4.5
[image: Visual studio screenshot for .net 4.5]

Comment: what controls is disabled in the new project? can you provide a screenshot in your question?

Comment: I'm having the same thing in .Net Core. This applies for ALL controls on the form. Whatever control you will select, you can't use the arrows on Document Outline panel (arrows are disabled).